# Get sessionID from req object without using express-session

Tags: javascript, express, session

I heard somewhere that I can use a property in the req object called `sessionID` but when I used it, it was undefined. The property is not set. Is there a way to uniquely identify a client without using express's session? Because it would require me to rewrite my whole back-end.

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req)
    var signup = auth.signup(req.body.un, req.body.email, req.body.pw, req.body.pc, req.sessionID);
    if (signup !== 1) {
        res.render("signup", { title, err: signup })
    } else {
        res.redirect("/dashboard")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.sessionID` is a custom field added to the req object via middleware, in some cases this would be via `express-session` but you could attach it in anyway you want. For example, you could create some middleware which reads a cookie or header value, extracts what you define as the session id, and attaches it to the req object directly.

If you're using some other sort of authentication then this should be fairly trivial to introduce a piece of middleware to translate this over. However you have no authentication built at the moment, then you won't have the data to make this work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it happens, I ended up rewriting the authentication system, then using `express-session` - works wonders!

Comment: Express-session solves a lot of issues. If this answer is valid for your question, would you mind ticking it as so? Alternatively you might consider writing your own answer if this one wasn't good enough :) It's always useful for people searching in the future!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i usually do that. but thanks for your answer.